# Multiple Pipelines in the queue using same executors and one goes offline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I feel like this is certainly a situation someone has run into before but I haven't been able to think up a non-trivial solution for my use case:

- Lets say I have two pipelines, P1 and P2, that do stuff and both need the same two executors/slaves/nodes A and B
- P1 enters the queue first and takes both A and B and starts doing it's stuff in parallel (using parallel)
- Then P2 enters the queue while A and B are being used, still, by P1;
  A and B are still online but they're unavailable for P2 to use (you'd
  see it waiting for the executors to be available in the console, for
  example)
- However, B fails and has the node taken offline on failure
- P1 completes with A eventually passing and B failed and took the node
  offline.
- Perhaps, depending on timing, P2 started using A when it passed.
- P2 will run A to completion but will wait forever until node B is
  brought online again

How can one check in the pipeline P2 that node B is offline and just break out?

If the node was offline at the start of P2 then it's easy to check and exclude it. However, if B is online when P2 enters the queue and sets up the parallel runs of A and B and sits and waits for them to be available and one of them goes offline then how does the pipeline get notified it's offline and move on to do whatever? Doesn't seem to happen automatically and I can't figure out how to check inside a node block that itself is offline (B checking if it itself is offline).

Here's a simple pipeline groovy script I made to help me figure out the issue:

```
// Branches for parallel node runs
def branches = [:]
// Nodes.  In real setup this would only contain nodes that are online at the time the pipeline runs
def node_names = ["A", "B"]
// Short sleep time of 15 seconds.  Later, it'll get reduced to 5 if the node name is B
def sleep_time = 15

// Loop through the nodes and create the data in the branch list to run in                             parallel on at the end
node_names.each { node_name ->
    println node_name

    branches["node_" + node_name] = {
        node(node_name) {
            // If the node that is being looked at is B then set the sleep time to 5 so that it runs
            // a shorter time than A.  Later, it's hardcoded to fail B and take it offline.  This way
            // A stays in the queue running and B is done and offline.
            def temp_sleep_time = sleep_time
            if (node_name == "B") {
                temp_sleep_time = 5
            }

            timestamps {
                stage("pre-build") {
                    println "Prebuilding " + node_name + "!"
                    sleep time: temp_sleep_time, unit: 'SECONDS'
                    println "Done with pre-build!"
                }
                stage("build") {
                    println "Building " + node_name + "!"
                    sleep time: temp_sleep_time, unit: 'SECONDS'
                    println "Done with build!"
                }
                stage("post-build") {
                    println "Post building " + node_name + "!"
                    if (node_name == "B") {
                        println "Taking node offline and failing build!"
                        takeNodeOffline("Derp", "B")
                        currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
                        return
                    }
                    sleep time: temp_sleep_time, unit: 'SECONDS'
                    println "Done with post-build!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
parallel branches
```

Is this possible? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, P2 would indeed wait forever. But as you are using the agent-per-stage approach instead of one agent for the whole pipeline, P2 wouldn't occupy any resources while it is waiting. The solution is that you provide not only one each, but multiple A and B nodes. In that case, B would only wait when all nodes of a kind are offline until one becomes available, which is what you usually want. Besides that, you could use a timeout directive to kill the pipeline or a stage after a certain amount of time:

```
options { timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') }
```

For further info, read https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  A timeout is certainly a way to do it.  

Another way is to spin wait until ALL resources are available and remove all offline nodes from consideration before starting it.

I'm not sure I fully understand your other solution; are you saying to just spin up more resources (more As and Bs) and then any other pipelines that come into the queue can just grab the available resources (that are definitely not offline)?

Comment: That’s exactly what I proposed.

Comment: Thanks.  That is, indeed, the optimal way to do it.  Unfortunately for me, A and B are actual hardware so I can't just create new ones on the fly.  I've gotten around this issue, now, by simply waiting for resources to become available and removing offline nodes from consideration.